# Ошибка "on a null object reference" в Recyclerview

Tags: android, recyclerview

Пытаюсь сделать пагинацию следуя по одной статьи.
Есть класс Posts , есть в этом классе поле User.
Ошибка обращения именно к полям User. При обращении к полям "Posts" (postsList.get(position).getTitle()) проблем нет.
Заполняю адаптер Recyclerview

```
        feedFragmentViewModel.getFeed().observe(getActivity(), new Observer<List<Posts>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Posts> posts) {
                adapter.addAll(posts);
            }
        });
```

Почему-то в onBindViewHolder, когда я пытаюсь получить данные из поля User получаю ошибку User.getName()' on a null object reference.

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Posts posts = postsList.get(position);
        Log.d(TAG,posts.getUser().getName()); //// on a null object reference
        Log.d(TAG,posts.getTitle()); //получаю значение
}
```

А если в методе addAll получить то же поле, то никаких проблем.

```
   public void addAll(List<Posts> mcList) {
        for (Posts post : mcList) {
            Log.d(TAG, post.getUser().getName()); // Получаю поле User name 
            add(post);
        }
    }

///////
   public void add(Posts post) {
        postsList.add(post);
        notifyItemInserted(postsList.size() - 1);
    }

    public void addLoadingFooter() {
        isLoadingAdded = true;
        add(new Posts());
    }
```

```
public class Posts
{
    private User user;

    private String title;

    private String post_text;
}
```

Comment: есть два варианта - либо у вас пользователь null либо его имя, попробуйте вывести в логи значения этих полей чтобы посмотреть, и так же советую добавить обработку пустого значения чтобы приложение не падало

Comment: Да, пользователь был равен null.  Вызвав метод  loadNextPage() еще в одном месте, проблема как-то решилась.

Странно то, почему именно User был равен нулю? Ведь если я передаю в адаптер список Posts ```adapter.addAll(posts);``` 
то поле User Класса Posts должен же заполняться. Так в методе addAll он же заполняется, в этом методе могу получить значения поля User класса Posts. А в методе onBindViewHolder, получаю заполненными только поля Posts (title, postText);

Comment: Можете подсказать 1 момент. Почему в метод add передается пустой объект?                     ```public void addLoadingFooter() {
        isLoadingAdded = true;
        add(new Posts());
    }```

Comment: если я правильно понимаю то add(new Posts());  добавляет новый объект класса, и он пустой, вы его никак не заполняете если я не ошибаюсь

Comment: @Flocky, мы не знаем по какой статье вы делали и не видели полный код ни ваш, ни из статьи. Вероятно это нужно для реализации индикатора загрузки - в адаптере проверять настоящий элемент или пустой и на месте пустого показывать текст, прогресс и т.п. После загрузки он убирается и добавляются новые элементы. Как-то так...